# Is [space-travel] on topic here?

Tags: discussion, status-review, tags, specific-tag

Is [space-travel](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-travel) on topic for the site? To me it looks like a big red flag that the question actually belongs on Space Exploration, or in the more hypothetical cases Worldbuilding.

Looking at the questions that have this tag, a lot of them are closed/migrated, and many of the ones that have not been would in my opinion be candidates for closure/migration if necromancy was not a concern. The relevant page in the [Help Center](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states that artificial satellites whose purpose is not related to astronomy is off-topic, and for the astronomical aspects we have [artificial-satellite](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-satellite) and [space-telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-telescope).

Comment: If you're satisfied with my response, please upvote as this is an issue that will require CM intervention, and I will need to demonstrate that the community wants action here.

Comment: This is on the CM team's backlog, and we'll get back to you once someone gets assigned to have a look at your request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right, just about every one of those is off topic (ok, some *may* be borderline), and many of them are already closed. I don't really see much of an on-topic use for this tag anyway, so it really needs to go.

Comment: `+1` I agree that the tag should be removed, its very existence conflicts with the clear distinction between Astronomy and Space SE.

Comment: If we added a tag warning to this block, would it make sense to say something pointing at the [space.se] on topic page letting them know that it may be a valid alternative but to check the scope?

Comment: @Catija That sounds great, actually!